# Could Android Device use camera, Bluetooth, GPS all from linux board via USB?

Tags: java, android, c, linux, driver

I'm developing a system in which Android connects to the Linux development board via USB. Android can not use its own Camera, BlueTooth, GPS function, Android must use the Camera, BlueTooth, GPS function in the Linux development board. I want to know what should be done to achieve the above functions.

I know there's some solutions about how to connect USB Camera with Android. But I don't know how to use the camera, bluetooth,gps all together in linux board via USB, the there's only one USB port available.

Could you help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Its not possible without spending changing Android core.

Comment: You'd have to write something in linux that makes that data available somewhere, then when Android connects it reads that. There's no magic way to do it.  Whats the use case where Android is connected via USB?

Comment: @mvp@Blundell Thank you. Well, I know it's quite strange...But my company wants to implement a dual-system. The Linux board is the only user interface that users can see. And there're cameras, GPS, BlueTooth on linux.but the Android board must be installed in an invisible place...There will be a program on the Linux board to switch between android and linux.